# How to return an object instead of array in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

I meet a question in Codeignter when I try to get an object return, some of controllers codes are

```
$sql = $this->user_model->userdetail($data);
    if ($sql) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "status" => "0",
            "message" => "",
            "data" => $sql
    ));
    exit();
}
```

And the model codes are

```
function userdetail($data) {
    $id = $data["id"];
    $sql = "select email, name from user where id='".$id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

I can get the result

```
{
    "status": "0",
    "message": "",
    "data": [
    {
        "email": "lily@email.com",
        "name": "lily"
    }
    ]
}
```

here the `data` is an array, but it should be an object, the above result should like this

```
{
    "status": "0",
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "email": "lily@email.com",
        "name": "lily"
    }
}
```

And I changed `return $query->result_array();` to `return $query->result_object();` in model code, but it doesn't work, what should I do here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try $query->result()

Comment: @Saeed.Gh Tried, still the same

Comment: provide what do you have in result and which version of Codeigniter you use

Comment: @Saeed.Gh v3, btw, from the documents, resualt()===result_object()

Comment: what result_object() provides? error/null object ?

Comment: @Saeed.Gh both result() and result_object() return object.

Comment: I know. what does it provide for you now?

Comment: @Saeed.Gh I think I find the reason, please check my answer.

Comment: every thing is fine with the result. by calling result (default is object) or result_object you will get all rows as object. if you need one row simply call $query->row(), when you need to have multi rows it would be an array (multi dimension or array of objects) its not an object because there is no attribute there are indexes 0,1,2,...

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the reason, in model

```
return $query->result_array(); // also can be changed to return $query->result_object(); or return $query->result();
```

They can return array or object, and in controller file

```
$sql = $this->user_model->userdetail($data);
```

`$sql` should be array or object, but actually it return a Multidimensional Arrays like this

return result() or result_object()

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [email] => lily@email.com
            [name] => lily
        )

)
```

return result_array()

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => lily@email.com
            [name] => lily
        )

)
```

it's strange.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter `$query->result_array();` is used to return result in array Format.

To get result in object format use `$query->result();` like

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
```

For single row use `$query->result_array()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need JSON_FORCE_OBJECT in json_encode.

```
echo json_encode(array(
        "status" => "0",
        "message" => "",
        "data" => $sql), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **problem** is you are using **result_array()**. You have to use **row()** instead, *row()* function will give you the object instead of array.

The model code:

```
function userdetail($data) {
    $id = $data["id"];
    $sql = "select email, name from user where id='".$id."'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->row() : 0;
}
```